# dbus/dbus.h no such file or directory when building to arm

Tags: c++, c, cross-compiling, dbus

I'm trying to cross compile my project to arm to use it on a raspberry pi but it can't find dbus. Which was easily find when I was compiling classically.
I'm using cmake I've added dbus-1 to target link library and I'm using arm-linux-gnueabihf to cross compile.

Any idea?

EDIT: add my CMakeLists.txt :

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

FIND_PACKAGE(glib2) # bluetooth
include_directories(${GLIB2_INCLUDE_DIRS}) # bluetooth

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/gdbus)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/attrib)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/src)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/src/shared)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/btio)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/lib)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/client)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/emulator)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/monitor)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez)
include_directories(/usr/include/dbus)
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fpermissive" )
# Search every source files
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

include_directories (/usr)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/gdbus SRC_BLUEZ_GDBUS)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/client SRC_BLUEZ_CLIENT)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/btio SRC_BLUEZ_BTIO_LIST)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/attrib SRC_BLUEZ_ATTRIB_LIST)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/emulator SRC_BLUEZ_EMULATOR)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/lib SRC_BLUEZ_LIB)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/monitor SRC_BLUEZ_MONITOR)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/src SRC_BLUEZ_SRC)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/src/shared SRC_BLUEZ_SRC_SHARED)


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})

# Library used in test
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}-lib 
                                Thread.cpp
                                NetworkThread.cpp 
                                UdpSocket.cpp)
add_library(MyBluezLib-lib
${SRC_BLUEZ_SRC} ${SRC_BLUEZ_LIB} 
    ${SRC_BLUEZ_GDBUS} ${SRC_BLUEZ_CLIENT} ${SRC_BLUEZ_BTIO_LIST} ${SRC_BLUEZ_ATTRIB_LIST} ${SRC_BLUEZ_EMULATOR} 
    ${SRC_BLUEZ_SRC_SHARED} ${SRC_BLUEZ_MONITOR})

# Link libraries
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (${PROJECT_NAME} 
                        pthread 
                        glog
                        bluetooth
                        ${GLIB2_LIBRARIES} #bluetooth
                        readline
                        expat
                        dbus-1
                        dl
                        MyBluezLib-lib
                        )
```

And this is my make call and his answear :

```
Scanning dependencies of target MyBluezLib-lib
[  1%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/MyBluezLib-lib.dir/home/grosalex/job/stageING3/bluez/src/rfkill.c.obj
In file included from /home/grosalex/job/stageING3/bluez/src/rfkill.c:39:0:
/home/grosalex/job/stageING3/bluez/src/adapter.h:29:23: erreur fatale: dbus/dbus.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include <dbus/dbus.h>

                   ^
```

compilation terminée.

Comment: Hi, can you edit your post by adding your project architecture and your compile command line please.

Comment: Please be more descriptive and clear in your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What embedded Linux distro is running on your RPi? You can also take a look at [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/). It can make your cross-compilation tasks easier.

Comment: I've add some detail do you need something more?
My rpi is running under raspbian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see, you have wrong include directory for dbus. You have `include_directories(/usr/include/dbus)` and in my host Linux I have following include flags, if I issue `pkg-config --cflags dbus-glib-1`:

```
-pthread -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib64/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include
```

Try to configure this include:

```
include_directories(/usr/include/dbus-1.0)
```

Comment: solve the problem but in my /usr/include the dbus folder is a link to dbus-1.0 so I don't understand why it was not working, is there any explanation?
thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Have you tried `include_directories(/usr/include/dbus/)`, i.e. add `/` after dbus?

Comment: yes it doesn't work but include_directories(/usr/include/dbus-1.0) did but I just can't understant why?